# Возвращение тип класса наследователя в функции другого класса наследователя

Tags: c++

Есть абстрактный класс BasicUnit:

```
#pragma once
#include "iostream"

//file BasicUnit.h
using namespace std;

class BasicUnit {

protected:
    int health;

public:
    enum UnitType
    {Builder, Soldier, Town, Home};

    virtual void showHealth();

    BasicUnit();
    BasicUnit(int a); 

    virtual ~BasicUnit(); 
};
```

От него наследуется класс Builder:

```
 #include "BasicUnit.h"
#include "Home.h"

class Builder : public BasicUnit {
public:
    Builder();
    Builder(int a);
    int chopTree();
    ~Builder();
    Home buildHome(); // Ошибка здесь
};
```

В третьем классе Home я хочу как возвращаемый тип задать Builder, но компилятор выдает ошибку что Builder не существует в BasicUnit.

```
#include "BasicUnit.h"
#include "Builder.h"
#include "iostream"


using namespace std;

class Home : public BasicUnit {

public:
    Home();
    Builder createBulder(); //Ошибка здесь 
    ~Home();

};
```

Как правильно сделать возвращение типа Builder?
Спасибо

Comment: Циклическое включение заголовочных файлов. Избавляйтесь от циклического включения заголовочных файлов.

Comment: @AnT скажите, а где конкретно есть цикл? Компилятор не ругается.

Comment: Home и BasicUnit включают друг друга. А он и не должен ругаться, формально это не ошибка.

Comment: @AnT насколько я понял, что вся проблема заключалась в том, что в Builder был включен Home.h. Сейчас программа работает, но: следующим моим шагом будет функция createHome() как раз в классе Builder, которая будет возвращать класс Home. Как вернуть класс Home, если его нельзя подключить?

Comment: Объявите класс Home раньше класса Builder. Только объявите, не определяйте.

Comment: @ArtemLP в итоге решил все переносом в два .h файла, каждый из которых обезопасил от циклического включения. Теперь все работает прекрасно.